# ASP.Net Indentity - automatically sign in users with two-factor authentication enabled

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-identity, two-factor-authentication

We're using two-factor authentication via SMS on our current website. Once a user has verified their phone number, we thought it would be a good idea to demand occasional random checks as an additional layer of security.

To enable this, I put this in the Login method on the controller:

```
var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: true);
switch (result)
{
    // other cases
    case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
        int challengeFrequency = Convert.ToInt16(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ChallengeFrequency"]);
        Random rnd = new Random();
        if (rnd.Next(1, challengeFrequency + 1) == 1)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("SendCode", new { returnUrl = returnUrl });
        }
        else
        {
            var token = await UserManager.GenerateTwoFactorTokenAsync(user.Id, "Phone Code");
            await SignInManager.TwoFactorSignInAsync("Phone Code", token, false, false);
            return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
        }
}
```

But when the user is *not* challenged, this results in them having to login in twice before being allowed into the site.

Stepping through the code I can see it's generating the phone verification token as expected. And I understood that the call to TwoFactorSignInAsync should wait until the login process was completed before proceeding. However on the first pass `User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` is false, while on the second, it's true.

Why is this failing to sign-in the user on the first attempt, but succeeding on the second?